# How do I find $E\lfloor X \rfloor$ when $X \sim \text{exp}(2)$?

Tags: random-variables, ceiling-and-floor-functions, expected-value, exponential-distribution

I am trying to learn from my mistakes, and faced the following problem:

> Let $X \sim \exp(2)$ and $Y=\lfloor X \rfloor$, compute $E[Y]$.

Well my false attempt was:

First compute the PDF of Y:

$ F_Y(t)=P(Y\leq t)=P(\lfloor x \rfloor \le X)$ (:I guess the problem is here) $=P(t\leq X\leq t+1)=F_X(t+1)-F_X(t)=(1-e^{-2t-2})-(1-e^{-2t})=e^{-2}e^{-2t}-e^{-2t}$

Then I would like to take the derivative:

$f_y(t)=-2e^{-2}e^{-2t}+2e^{-2t}$ (I always consider the case where $t\geq 0$ )

Then:

$E[Y]=-e^{-2}\int_{0}^{\infty}2te^{-2t}+\int_{0}^{\infty}2te^{-2t}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2e^{-2}}$

I can guess that I have made the following wrong assumptions but I will really appreciate to know what exactly is wrong:

Y is obviously discrete, but I computed $F_Y, f_y, E[Y]$ as if it was continous - but I am not completely sure what is wrong with that since I only used X to compute Y, and since X is continuous I though I could do that.

**Edit** another approach Iv'e tried was to compute that directly:

$E[Y]=\int_{0}^{\infty} \lfloor x \rfloor f_X(x) dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1} \lfloor x \rfloor f_X(x) dx$
But now I am not sure what do do, what can I do with that floor function?

Comment: $Y$ is a discrete random variable; no differentiating the cdf. How to find pmf from cdf? And since you are asked for the expectation only, why not find directly $$E\lfloor X\rfloor=\int \lfloor x\rfloor f_X(x)\,dx$$

Comment: @StubbornAtom hmmm, I am not sure

Comment: Compute $P\{Y=n\}$ for each $n$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I edited my second attempt

Comment: Yes, go ahead. It is straightforward integration and then summation when you consider what is $\lfloor x\rfloor $ when $n\le x<n+1$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks, another question: what I did with the $F_X(t+1) - F_X(t)$ was wrong?

Comment: Find the pmf directly.

Comment: @StubbornAtom how is that straightforward? I can guess that it is something like $ \sum_{0}^{\infty}n \int_{n}^{n+1}f_X(x)dx$ but what is the justification? it makes sense in my head but nothing more